# Bone matrix assignment behaviour change in Blender 2.80

Tags: armature, import, matrix

I am trying to port an armature importer add-on from Blender 2.79 to Blender 2.8x.

After the bone is being created the bone matrix is set.

But the assignment of the bone matrix has a different behaviour in Blender 2.82a compared to the older Blender 2.79b.

I created a small script that works for both Blender versions to reproduce this behaviour:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *

def new_armature(name: str) -> bpy.types.Object:
    armature = bpy.data.armatures.new(name)
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, armature)

    if bpy.app.version[1] >= 80:
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    else:
        bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj

    return obj    

obj = new_armature('human')
armature = obj.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

new_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('Bone.000')

new_bone.head = Vector([0, 0, 0])
new_bone.tail = Vector([1, 0, 0])

bone_matrix = Matrix(([0,0,1,0],[0,-1,0,-6],[-1,0,0,6],[0,0,0,1]))
print("bone_matrix:\n", bone_matrix)

new_bone.matrix = bone_matrix
print("new_bone.matrix:\n", new_bone.matrix)
```

Running that script in Blender 2.79b and Blender 2.82a gives me the following outputs:

```
user@desktop:~/workspace/blender$ blender2.79b --python test2.py --background
Read prefs: /home/user/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /opt/blender/2.79b/2.79/python
bone_matrix:
 <Matrix 4x4 ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            (-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>
new_bone.matrix:
 <Matrix 4x4 (0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000,  0.0000)
            (0.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000, -6.0000)
            (1.0000,  0.0000, -0.0000,  6.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>

Blender quit
user@desktop:~/workspace/blender$ blender2.82a --python test2.py --background
Blender 2.82 (sub 7) (hash 375c7dc4caf4 built 2020-03-12 05:30:40)
Read prefs: /home/user/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /opt/blender/2.82a/2.82/python
bone_matrix:
 <Matrix 4x4 ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            (-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>
new_bone.matrix:
 <Matrix 4x4 (-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>

Blender quit
```

As you can see, the `new_bone.matrix` matrix differes between these versions.

Updating the scene also does not change anything.

Can you give me a hint how to get the Blender 2.79b behaviour in Blender 2.82a?

My platform is Linux with Kubuntu 19.10 x64.

Answer (score 0):

There is bone_matrix in left-handed system. It makes no sense to consider the differences between versions when the wrong parameters are inputted into Blender.

```
bone_matrix in left-handed system:
 <Matrix 4x4 ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            (-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>

bone_matrix in right-handed system:
 <Matrix 4x4 ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            ( 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It's possible that the matrix is wrong. The origin matrix targeted directX, so left-handed system. Maybe there is something wrong with the matrix conversion from directX coordinate system to blender's coordinate system.
Do you have a solution how to convert a matrix from directx coordinate system to blender coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

**The resultant rotation of both matrices is equivalent.**

If we look at the quaternion  rotation of each matrix can get the angular difference

Using 2.90 alpha and tacking following onto script

```
print("bone_matrix:\n", bone_matrix)
print(bone_matrix.to_euler())
new_bone.matrix = bone_matrix
print("new_bone.matrix:\n", new_bone.matrix)

print(new_bone.matrix.to_euler())

q = bone_matrix.to_quaternion() # M1
q2 = new_bone.matrix.to_quaternion() # M2
print(q, q2)
ad = q.rotation_difference(q2)

axis, angle = ad.to_axis_angle()
from math import degrees

print("Rotate M1", degrees(angle), "about axis", axis, "to match M2")
```

Output

```
bone_matrix:
 <Matrix 4x4 ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            (-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>
<Euler (x=-3.1416, y=1.5708, z=0.0000), order='XYZ'>
new_bone.matrix:
 <Matrix 4x4 (-1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000, -6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000,  6.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>
<Euler (x=0.0000, y=-0.0000, z=3.1416), order='XYZ'>
<Quaternion (w=0.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=1.0000)>
<Quaternion (w=0.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=1.0000)>

Rotate M1 0.0 about axis <Vector (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)> to match M2
```

The quaternions are same.

Looking at the Euler angles will notice that the end results (in degrees)

```
Euler((360, 180, 0))
```

is equivalent to

```
Euler((0, 0, 360))
```

This is often seen as [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) in Eulers were two eqivalent rotation matrices flip flop.

Would favour the more *well formed* nature of M2 with values on the principle diagonal.

Suggestion, using quaternion rotation for bones makes sure they have a singular value per rotation.